# How to replace one query string via .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, url

I have a site (with OpenCart CMS, if it's important) with a lot of urls and the thing is sometimes a filter is applied to the pages on the site via a GET paramter, e.g. `http://example.net/category?attr_id=42`  or `http://example.net/category/sub-category/sub-category2/product?attr_id=42`. Also, sometimes 'attr_id' part goes like `&attr_id=42`
I just want to replace this particular GET parameter with `/part-id=42`. This means I want to get a substring from the URL string and replace `?attr_id=42` or `&attr_id=42` with `/part-id=42`, generally speaking.

I.e. I want to get `http://example.net/category/part-id=42` or `http://example.net/category/sub-category/sub-category2/product/part-id=42`

How can I implement this via .htaccess? Or in some other way?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what OC version you're using, but I believe you can accomplish this by going to your admin dashboard, go to SEO and go to the submenu for SEO Regex.

See my attached screenshot

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately, this is not the case because I use OC v2.